# CASE in Eloquent Laravel not running the function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

The following is my query and the CASE part is not executing:

```
$deposit = CurrentTransaction::select('current_transaction.id', 'user.name', 'current_transaction.amount', 'current_transaction.status', 'current_transaction.type', 'current_transaction.refer_id', 'current_transaction.msg', 'current_transaction.remarks', 'current_transaction.created_by', 'current_transaction.created_at')
->join('user', 'current_transaction.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
->where('current_transaction.amount', '>', '0')
->where(function ($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('CASE WHEN current_transaction.created_by = current_transaction.user_id THEN "true" ELSE "false" END AS "result"'))->where('result', 'false');
})->get();
```

and the syntax error around where('result', 'false') part.

---

**Update**

The structure of database:

```
Schema::create('current_transaction', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->decimal('amount', 30, 8);
        $table->boolean('status')->default(1);
        $table->integer('type')->default(1);
        $table->integer('refer_id');
        $table->integer('created_by');
        $table->integer('updated_by');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I want to find out the rows where created_by is not equal to user_id
join the user table, and get the user.name with user_id
and amount more than 0.

Comment: *What* syntax error? What, *exactly* does it say?

Answer (score 2):

You can update your query like this:

```
$deposit = CurrentTransaction::join('user', 'current_transaction.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
            ->where('amount', '>', '0')
            ->where('created_by' , '!=', 'user_id')
            ->select('current_transaction.id', 
                     'user.name', 'current_transaction.amount', 
                     'current_transaction.status', 
                     'current_transaction.type', 
                     'current_transaction.refer_id', 
                     'current_transaction.msg', 
                     'current_transaction.remarks', 
                     'current_transaction.created_by', 
                     'current_transaction.created_at')
            ->get();
```

Comment: This one look great! but i don't know why the "true" are still displayed

Comment: @1myb Because I included `DB::raw('CASE WHEN current_transaction.created_by = current_transaction.user_id THEN "true" ELSE "false" END AS "result"'))`

Comment: Yes still the same. the successful result should be 500+ only but now returning 4k results

Comment: Based on a query I don't understand what you want. Please provide table structure, what you are getting and what do you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The following part will need to use DB::raw:

```
 ->where('current_transaction.created_by' ,'!=', DB::raw('current_transaction.user_id'))
```

Comment: DB::raw doesn't make sense. You can simply put condition like this. `->where('created_by' , '!=', 'user_id')` no need to use current_transaction.created_by